# How do I stop Github's web editor from adding a newline to the end of file?

Tags: github

I recently used Github's web editor to propose a change to a project. However, it added a newline to the end of the file, and that is against project's style rules (some sort of compatibility issue).

I've tried simply removing the newline, but after committing all I get is this:

> **No changes to show.**
>
> This commit has no content.

I've dug through github settings, but haven't found anything that might be related to newlines or end-of-files. I don't know anything about git command line, or any way to use github other than their web editor. I barely even understand how to clone a repository.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

> How do I fix this?

Unless you work at GitHub, you can't. You have to use the git command line.

I am surprised they still haven't fixed this. It makes the web editor unusable for projects with blocking lint checks.